# Calling a stored procedure from CodeIgniter's Active Record class

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, codeigniter, activerecord

In my **CI application** setup to query a `mssql` database. I want to execute a `stored procedure` from `active record`. But I can't get hold of any solid documentation.

Does anyone have any experience with calling stored procs with `CodeIgniter` and/or `Active Record` and passing in parameters?

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes , try this in your model.

```
$this->db->query("call {storedprocedure function name} ");
```

if you encounter trouble calling more than 1 stored procedure at a time you need to add the following line

```
/* ADD THIS FUNCTION IN SYSTEM/DATABASE/DB_ACTIVE_REC */
/* USAGE $this->db->freeDBResource($this->db->conn_id); */
function freeDBResource($dbh){
    while(mysqli_next_result($dbh)){
            if($l_result = mysqli_store_result($dbh)){
              mysqli_free_result($l_result);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I almost waste 5 hour to figure out this problem ,finally i got the right place.There was some mistake in the code for calling the function to free the object but i changed "$this->db->freeDBResource($this->db->conn_id);" to "$this->freeDBResource($this->db->conn_id);" ,and It worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

If you are using later versions of codeigniter with mssql or sqlsrv with  stored procedures, using 'CALL' as in `query('CALL procedureName($param1,$params,....)')` may not work.

In the case of MSSQL use:

```
$this->db->query('EXEC procedureName')
```

OR

```
$this->db->query('EXEC procedureName $param1 $param2 $param3,...')
```

In some cases you might need to turn on some constants for the driver. In this case run:

```
$this->db->query('Set MSSQL constant ON )
```

before running your regular query.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following function to **class CI_DB_mysqli_driver** in /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

```
    function free_db_resource()
    {
        while(mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id))
        {
            if($l_result = mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id))
            {
                mysqli_free_result($l_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

and use it after the procedure call

```
$this->db->free_db_resource();
```

Thanks to [wework4web](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507773/wework4web)

Answer (score 1):

A simply way to call your stored procedure which has parameters is by using query() method provided by database library of Codeigniter.

In your model:-

```
function call_procedure(){
    $call_procedure ="CALL TestProcedure('$para1', '$para2', @para3)";
    $this->db->query($call_procedure);
    $call_total = 'SELECT @para3 as Parameter3';
    $query = $this->db->query($call_total);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This a little modification from above answer. If you are using codeigniter 3 place this code in /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:

```
function free_db_resource()
{
    do
    {
        if($l_result = mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id))
        {
            mysqli_free_result($l_result);
        }
    }
    while(mysqli_more_results($this->conn_id)  && mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id));
}
```

Then just call the function like others suggested here.

Comment: Perfect. The above function may throw error if there are no multiple records.  This works exactly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public function callSp_model{
   $sql = "CALL Materialwise_PURC_report(?,?,?)";
    $query = $this->lite_db->query($sql,array($supplierid,$fromdate,$todate));
    return $query->result_array(); }
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer