# Call multiple stored procedures from Codeigniter last result contains the previous

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures, multiple-resultsets

I'm using this library in Codeigniter to retrieve multiple result sets from stored procedures :

```
class Multi_Results
{
   private $CI, $Data, $mysqli, $ResultSet;

   /**
   * The constructor
   */

   function __construct()
   {
     $this->CI =& get_instance();
     $this->Data = '';
     $this->ResultSet = array();
     $this->mysqli = $this->CI->db->conn_id;
   }

    public function GetMultiResults($SqlCommand)
    {
        /* execute multi query */
        if (mysqli_multi_query($this->mysqli, $SqlCommand)) {
            $i=1;
            do
            {
                if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result()) 
                {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $this->Data[$i][] = $row;
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
                $i++; 
            }
            while ($this->mysqli->more_results() && $this->mysqli->next_result());
        }
        return $this->Data;
    }

}
```

I'm calling the procedure from the controller like

```
$result_array = $this->multi_results->GetMultiResults("CALL procedure_name($input_1, '$input_2')");
```

It does what it is supposed to do. The problem arises when I call 2 DIFFERENT procedures from the controller one after another and assign the results to different variables.
When I var_dump the second (last) result, it contains also the result set from the 1st result.
I have checked the connection dbdriver in database.php (it is set to MSQLI), I tried to implement some suggestions like :
 [CodeIgniter active records' problems calling multiple stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721181/codeigniter-active-records-problems-calling-multiple-stored-procedures) and [Calling a stored procedure from CodeIgniter's Active Record class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827752/calling-a-stored-procedure-from-codeigniters-active-record-class)
They both propose a solution with 'mysqli_free_result' however that is already done in the addon library (as you can see in the code snippet above).

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate `$this->data = ''` into the function GetMultiResults() instead into constructor.
 I think this will solve your problem.